# Prism (WPF) - CancelEventArgs.Cancel already set to true

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I'm dealing with a really frustrating issue whilst attempting to use Prism's command actions to cancel closing a shell based on a simple yes / no decision dialog.

When I close the shell, it immediately closes and the eventArgs.Cancel is set to true.

This makes no sense to me as I'm hooking into Closing not Closed and if Cancel is already set to true the shell shouldn't close?!

Interaction triggers in the view:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Closing">
        <prism:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Close}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

ICommand Property in VM

```
public ICommand Close { get; set; }
```

Hooking up in constructor

```
this.Close = new Prism.Commands.DelegateCommand<CancelEventArgs> (this.HandleClose);
```

Handler Method

```
private void HandleClose (CancelEventArgs eventArgs)
    {          
        log.LogDebug ($"Close requested");

        bool shouldCancel = CommonWindows.ShowConfirmationDialog ("Do you want to cancel before closing?", "CancelBeforeClose");

        if ( shouldCancel )
        {
            eventArgs.Cancel = true;
            return;
        }
            
        log.LogDebug ($"Closing window - {this.shellItem.ShellName} [{this.Title}]");

        this.eventAggregator.GetEvent<CloseShellEvent> ().Publish (this.shellItem.ShellName);
        this.isShellClosed = true;
    }
```

[image: Debugging handle method]

I'd appreciate any pointers I can get, cheers in advance!

Comment: Have you tried doing this as a simple code behind event handler instead of an event to command handler? Even just as an experiment?

Comment: Just tried that. CancelEventArgs comes through as false, set it to true and the window still closes..... Must be something I'm just not seeing yet.

Comment: Aren't you setting `Cancel` to true in the `HandleClose` method? It shouldn't be `true` when this method is called. Does it work if you remove the `ShowConfirmationDialog` stuff? I cannot reproduce your issue.